# Shapless coproduct sub-typing

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to emulate at least some aspects of union types in scala 2.13.

So far the best approach that meets my needs is `coproduct` from shapless. The only problem is that subtyping is not working as I expected. Here is an example:

```
import shapeless._

type ISB = Int :+: String :+: Boolean :+: CNil

type ISBSub = Int :+: String :+: CNil

implicitly[ISBSub <:< ISB] // error here
```

I'm trying to create a method with parameter of type `ISB` and want this `def` accept `ISBSub` as well.

```
def test(t: ISB) = ???

test(Coproduct[ISBSub](2)) // not working
```

Is there any way to achieve something like this with `coproduct`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given Shapeless's encoding of coproducts, it's not possible for this kind of subset relationship to be the same as subtyping. Instead there's a type class that provides evidence that one coproduct is a sub-union of another:

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> type ISB = Int :+: String :+: Boolean :+: CNil
defined type alias ISB

scala> type ISBSub = Int :+: String :+: CNil
defined type alias ISBSub

scala> shapeless.ops.coproduct.Basis[ISB, ISBSub]
res0: shapeless.ops.coproduct.Basis[Int :+: String :+: Boolean :+: shapeless.CNil,Int :+: String :+: shapeless.CNil]{type Rest = Boolean :+: shapeless.CNil} = shapeless.ops.coproduct$Basis$$anon$64@ddd69d2
```

This type class also allows you to convert values of either coproduct type in either direction:

```
import shapeless.ops.coproduct.Basis

def shrink[A <: Coproduct, B <: Coproduct](a: A)(implicit ev: Basis[A, B]): Option[B] =
  ev(a).toOption

def enlarge[A <: Coproduct, B <: Coproduct](b: B)(implicit ev: Basis[A, B]): A =
  ev.inverse(Right(b))
```

And then:

```
scala> shrink[ISB, ISBSub](Coproduct[ISB](1))
res0: Option[ISBSub] = Some(Inl(1))

scala> enlarge[ISB, ISBSub](Coproduct[ISBSub](1))
res1: ISB = Inl(1)
```

In general it's worth browsing through the contents of the `shapeless.ops` packages to get a sense of what kinds of operations are supported for things like coproducts.